# C# Run console application from another app in a new console window

Tags: c#, console

The second app is a console application and I want to see it's output window.

I know how to use `Process.Start()` but it doesn't show the console window for the app.
This is what I have tried:

```
Process.Start("MyApp.exe", "arg1 arg2");
```

So how to do it?

Comment: "I know how to use Process.Start()" please share with us your attempt. It would make things much easier to find the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I have to run `cmd` command with `/k` argument (to keep the console window open) and then my whole command-line:

```
var command = "MyApp.exe arg1 arg2";
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/k " + command);
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
process.Start();
//In case you need the output. But you have to wait enough for the output
//string text = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhapse [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2006/09/28/how-to-start-a-console-app-in-a-new-window-the-parents-window-or-no-window/) helps:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName, arg); 
info.CreateNoWindow = false;
info.UseShellExecute = true;
Process processChild = Process.Start(info);
```